# Update magento cart with “Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api”?

Tags: magento-1.7, api

I am trying to update cart with checkout/cart_product_api model. The function I use is,

```
public function updateCartAction() {

        $result = array();
        $apiModel = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart_product_api');


        $quoteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_id', null);
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id', null);

        $quoteId = 74;
        $store = 1;

        $productId = "51";
        $qty = "5";




        $productsData = array(
                                array(

                                        "product_id" => $productId,
                                        "qty" => $qty

                                      )
                             );


        $result = $apiModel->update($quoteId, $productsData, $store);





        print json_encode(array("result" => $result));



    }
```

Here I am trying to change quantity of product is `51` manually. It calls `update()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart/Product/Api.php` and the return value is true.

But the quantity remains unchanged! Why it happens? If anyone have a solution please do share with me.

Comment: How do you check that `the quantity remains unchanged`? Do you call `$apiModel->items($quoteId)` and see the same qty as it was before `update()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I need to put a `save()` in the `update` function in `checkout/cart_product_api` model, after setting quantity.

ie in `update()` in `mage/checkout/model/cart/product/api.php`, there is

```
 if ($productItem['qty'] > 0) {
                $quoteItem->setQty($productItem['qty']);
            }
```

It should be

```
 if ($productItem['qty'] > 0) {
                $quoteItem->setQty($productItem['qty'])->save();
            }
```

So, I override the `update()` and issue is resolved.

Comment: didn't work for me :(